# Category Rewrites

Tags: magento2.3.1

When selecting filters on category pages I get the standard URL of "?cat=45". Is there a way with standard Magento 2 or with an extension to get these to automatically rewrite to the created category page? The above example should redirect to "BMW" for example.

Thanks all.